# Android - SearchView - setTypeface not available

Tags: android, fonts, searchview

For some reason, I'm not able to setTypeface on a SearchView.
Here is my code to try to change the font:

```
searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchview_invite_friends_search_contact);
Typeface myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/myFont.ttf");
searchView.setTypeface(myFont);
```

**I defined it like this in a the xml:**

```
<SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:queryHint="@string/searchview_invite_friends_search_contact"
        android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:searchIcon="@drawable/icon_search"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:queryBackground="@color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SearchView contains a TextView which you first have to find to change its Typeface like this.

```
 TextView searchText = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
 searchText.setTypeface(<your Typeface>);
```

This is for the SearchView in the v7 Android Support library.

For the normal SearchView in the android.widget package see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30915643/3233251

Comment: Works definitely much better :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

TextView searchText = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
        Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/siemreap.ttf");
        searchText.setTypeface(type);

Comment: Try to examplain a little bit so they know what your suggesting. Give it context.

Answer (score 0):

A possibility via xml  (not tested across OS versions and devices):

Create a resource that is identical with **@layout/abc_search_view**. Lets name it "search_field.xml"

Inside the search_field.xml set the fontfamiliy on the "**<view class="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete>**" element.

```
...
<view class="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView$SearchAutoComplete"
              android:id="@+id/search_src_text"
              ...
              app:fontFamily="@font/[YOUR_FONT_RESOURCE]
              />
...
```

Create a resource style... lets name it **my_search_view_style**

```
<style name="my_search_view_style" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
   <item name="layout">@layout/search_field</item>
</style>here
```

Finaly set the **my_search_view_style** style on the SearchView

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    style="@style/my_search_view_style"
    ...
/>
```